# Divs not vertically aligning inside flex container

Tags: html, css

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Maya Writing</title>
        <style>

body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  margin: 35px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.gorc {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.l {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.imageside {
  display: flex;
  height: min-content;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
iframe {
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.pbx {
  width: 440px;
  height: 230px;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.r { text-align: right; }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<a class="l" href="index.html">Home</a>
<center><h1>Maya Writing</h1></center>
<div class="imageside">
<div><p class="pbx">Mayan hieroglyphic writing was a writing system used by the Maya people, it was used from 3rd century BC to the 17th century AD. Mayan was a mix of logosyllabic and ‏‏‎syllabogrammatic writing systems (Syllabograms are signs used to write syllables), although people thought it was entirely logosyllabic until recently. A logosyllabic is a language where every syllable is a word or morpheme, this is close to Mayan, but in Mayan some syllables are just a sound. Mayan was really complex because there are around 1000 symbols! This made it really hard for linguists to decipher. Mayan only had 5 vowels and 19 consonants compared to english's 20 vowels and 24 consonants, that isn't much.
</p></div>
<iframe width="440" height="230" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lgsQndSyfHg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="imageside">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m24!1m12!1m3!1d999.7262863339503!2d-87.43068604629732!3d20.214751884148985!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m9!3e6!4m3!3m2!1d20.214792199999998!2d-87.4302019!4m3!3m2!1d20.214764!2d-87.43018599999999!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sau!4v1621485999736!5m2!1sen!2sau" width="440" height="230" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
<div><p class="pbx">
</p></div>
</div>


<h4>External Resources Used</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Video: Video talking about Maya Glyphs</li> 
  <li>Map: Location of Tulum Mayan Ruins</li>
</ul>
<h4>Bibliography</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Britannica, The Editors of Encyclopaedia. "Mayan hieroglyphic writing". Encyclopedia Britannica, 21 Feb. 2007, <a href='https://www.britannica.com/topic/Mayan-hieroglyphic-writing'>https://www.britannica.com/topic/Mayan-hieroglyphic-writing</a>. Accessed 20 May 2021.</li> 
  <li>Cartwright, Mark. "<a href="https://www.worldhistory.org/article/655/maya-writing/">Maya Writing.</a>" World History Encyclopedia. World History Encyclopedia, 12 Feb 2014. Web. 26 May 2021.</li>
</ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i run this the text is not vertically aligned with the video iframe plz help
i put a black border around the text to chek and its just not vertically allignd there isnt a paragraph break in the text

it says i need more text so just so you know my browser is brave if that matters
MORE TEXT?! what more details are there omfg
omfg lorum ipsum dolor idk the latin base text thingo why do i need so much text there doesnt need this much detail

Comment: i found out that it is because "<p>" automatically puts a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Change your html structure**

```
<div class="imageside">
   <iframe></iframe>
   <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

**2. Change your styling for the div**

```
.imageside {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

This should center your content vertically in the correct way! Sheers